# Crystal Report Display no data

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a c# app which is connected to MySQL and I use Crystal Report, the problem is when I hit the button it receive the empty data as shown in below figure:

[image]

this is my code:

```
 MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from staff", con);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            MyDA.Fill(table);
            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
            MyDataSet ds = new MyDataSet();
            ds.Tables[0].Merge(table);
            rpt.Load(@"C:\Users\Hoger\documents\visual studio2012\Projects\PHC\PHC\cr.rpt");
            rpt.SetDataSource(ds);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
```

this is rpt:[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the dataset has data? May you post a screenshot of the rpt design?

Comment: Yes, I add the screenshot to pot

Comment: Is there only one table in your field explorer? Is there any chance that the detail section has the suppress field on? Shouldn't the field names be equal to the database table column names? May you try to rename them?

Comment: I was rename the column name, but I faced to this error <target> <source> have confilicting properties: DataType property mismatch

Comment: So, sounds like it is the right direction. Besides renaming the fields, change the field types accordingly to the database column types.

Comment: I changed my dataset type but also is not working, the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143201/discussion-between-hoger-qassim-and-heringer).